# Finding min and max values

Tags: c, max, min

I am trying to write a simple program that reads integers from a data file and outputs the minimum and maximum value. The first integer of the input file will indicate how many more integers will be read, and then the integers will be listed.

My program compiles without any problem, however, it returns values that are not part of the set in my test data file. Could anyone help with diagnose this issue?

```
int main(){
FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
int count;
int num;
int i;
int min = 0;
int max = 0;

fscanf (fp, "%d", &count);

for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    fscanf( fp, "%d", &i);  
    {   
    if (num < min)
        min = num;
    if (num > max)
        max = num;
    }
fclose (fp);

printf("Of the %d integers, the minimum value is %d and the maximum value is %d \n", count, min, max);}
```

Comment: `min` should probably be `INT_MAX` and `max` should probably be `INT_MIN`. That way you won't need something greater or less than 0 to change it. As it is, a file full of positive numbers will give a minimum of 0.

Comment: What is your dataset? And what is the current output? Like @chris says, since your min already starts at 0, if your datafile has no negative numbers, 0 is what will print out. You would have a similar problem with max if your file is full of negative numbers.

Comment: You didn't take even a moment to look at your code for **obvious** errors, like that you're reading numbers into your loop counter `i` rather than into `num`. Nor does it take much effort to see that the `{` is in totally the wrong place, nor that min and max both starting at 0 can't possibly be right. If you want to have any hope at all of writing usable programs, you need to develop better habits.

Answer (score 6):

Here are several bugs in your code.

First of all, change `i` to `num` in the loop in `fscanf` as cnicutar says. So that you can read the input correctly. And the left bracket `{` should be after the `for` loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)  {   // put the { here
    fscanf( fp, "%d", &num);
```

Secondly, your `min` and `max` is not correctly initiated. You should change them into `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`. And `#include <limits.h>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
......
int min = INT_MAX;
int max = INT_MIN;
```

Comment: Alright, I now get a correct min, but my max is still way off (the max of my test data set is 58 and my output gives me 2147383647).

Comment: Nothing strange for my code. So what are the whole test data?

Comment: That works fine on my machine. Check your code again. Have you corrected the bugs all?

Comment: @user01 "the max of my test data set is 58 and my output gives me 2147383647" -- that's because you set max = INT_MAX instead of INT_MIN. Programming requires care and precision.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to halfelf's changes, you'll want to initialize min to be some arbitrarily large value so that at least one of your input numbers is less than that value. Otherwise, if your input values are all positive, you'll end up displaying a min value of zero. Even better than the arbitrary large initial value is to use conditional logic to detect the first time through the loop and set the min and max to the first real value in your input stream. That avoids the dilemma around how large to start min (and how small to start max, which I didn't mention but is basically the inverse problem).

Answer (score 0):

Your `num` variable is empty and has not been used. You are comparing it with `max` and `min`. Hence `max` and `min` will store garbage vaues of `num`. Do it like this:

```
int main(){
FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
int count=0;
int i;
int min = 0;
int max = 0;
while (!feof(fp))
{
count++;
fscanf( fp, "%d", &i);
if (i < min)
min = i;
if (i > max)
max = i;
}
printf("Of the %d integers, the minimum value is %d and the maximum value is %d \n", count, min, max);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int min=0;
int max=0;
int n = sizeof(arr);
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   if (i==0){ 
     min=arr[i];
     max=arr[i];
   }
   else{
     if (arr[i]<min) min=arr[i];
     if (arr[i]>max) max=arr[i];
   }

}
```